# Shut down/log out, me menu absent in panel

Tags: 10.10, indicator, panel

I upgraded my Lucid installation to Maverick today via an alternate CD. Everything went fine but the shut down icon which provides the options to log out, suspend, hibernate etc. in the top right corner of the panel and the me menu which allows to set chat status are absent! I tried searching for suitable options in 'Add to Panel' but cannot find the exact solution - shut down provides option only to shut down, log out only to log out and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power/logout/suspend/hibernate option you are looking for is called the "Indicator Applet Session" in the "Add to Panel" Menu.